# Touch-enabled synthesizer like Animoog

Tags: music, windows-10

A friend showed me [Animoog](http://www.moogmusic.com/products/apps/animoog-0/) on his iPad. Since I have only a laptop with touch support, I'm looking for a similar toy.

- synthesizer
- customizable keyboard
- touch support and good usability. I don't want to fiddle, I want to play.
- Windows 10
- not to be purchased via the Windows Store but available separately
- less than 40 €

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [OpenLabs Stagelight](http://us.openlabs.com/stagelight)

- synthesizer *More than one but some are unlocked by in-App purchase*
- customizable keyboard *I don't think so at the moment - maybe suggest it in the [Forums](http://forums.openlabs.com/) - there is an active user community.*
- touch support and good usability. I don't want to fiddle, I want to play. *Multi-touch supported & User Friendly.*
- Windows 10 *Definately plus Android*
- not to be purchased via the Windows Store but available separately *Yes*
- less than 40 € *Basic Edition* ***Free***, Windows Core $9.99, Ultimate $49.99